# General strategy for +1/like in a website

Tags: database

I am developing a website that implements a feature for posts like Stackoverflow's +1 for question or facebook's *like* button. I'd like to know which strategy can offer the most efficient solution to do this? Should I use database or file system (or any other strategy)? Onother use of this strategy can be the total number of visitors for my website. Should I really open a connection to my database and update one field for every page load or is there another solution that I'm not aware of? Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to know why this gets a -1 vote? I mean is this that obvious?! I can imagine at least a hundred uses for this. Page counters, likes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you consider the cost of opening a file for read/write, reading/writing to the file, then closing the file compared to opening a db connection, reading/writing to the db, then closing the db connection, you'll probably find that there isn't a huge difference in either method.

The db is the more efficient option when using persistent db connections (always a good idea) since that means that you don't have to open and close the db connection.  For reporting purposes, it would be mush easier and faster to show the +1's, etc if they are stored in a db, also.

Unless your site is going to have a crazy number of people visiting and clicking the'+1' button, it honestly won't matter much in terms of speed. So, really it depends on your needs and which method will solve your specific issues

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The website's visitors are (supposed) a high number. I'm considering using this method for number of visits too so I think it needs to be fast enough. I totally agree with you on the cost of using file system compared to using DB but if you know a well-optimized solution for this (like Stackoverflow's), I would appreciate an example for this.

Comment: Sure thing; I don't know how stackoverlfow does it but I'll send you an example of how I would implement this tomorrow morning when I get to the office..

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but if you take a look at http://www.mikebryant.com/misc/like_table.png you'll see the table design I would most likely use to do this.  The 'page' column would ideally be a 'page_id' integer column with a foreign key to a page table. The 'user_id' column is in case you have registered users and want to track which users like what pages, etc.  The date column is just so you can report on what pages were 'liked' for a date range, etc.

Comment: Another thing... if you are using Java to write your app you might want to take a look at the Quartz scheduler (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). It is easy to use and will allow you to queue up these sorts of items in your database so they do not affect performance.  There may be similar tools for PHP, rails, .Net, etc as well.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comments. I'm using PHP and I would like to know how to minimize overhead on PHP if you know a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure about how to do that in PHP. The nature of PHP would make a custom thread queue at least quite difficult, most likely impossible.  One thing to be sure to do is to used persistent database connections via the mysql_pconnect method instead of using mysql_connect.  Good luck!